# Node Js Error Module.js 549

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

While starting my application, I get this error. I have already checked and seen that the required module is well installed, and also gave it global access.

```
Hussains-MacBook-Pro:NodeRest-Shop Hussain$ npm start

> noderest-shop@1.0.0 start /Users/Hussain/Desktop/Development/Web/NodeRest-Shop
> nodemon server.js

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'binary-extensions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Hussain/Desktop/Development/Web/NodeRest-Shop/node_modules/is-binary-path/inde
x.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! noderest-shop@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the noderest-shop@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Hussain/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T05_23_59_594Z-debug.log
```

Comment: install below package using `npm install binary-extensions --save`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `binary-extensions` module, as seen in your log:

> Error: Cannot find module 'binary-extensions'

It could be that you're missing some dependencies or forgot to include it.

You can install it using [npm](/questions/tagged/npm):

```
 npm install binary-extensions
```

And [include binaryExtensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-extensions) in your project:

```
const binaryExtensions = require('binary-extensions');
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running:

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

Comment: what does that do?

Answer (score -1):

Check your app.js file your index route should be 
`app.use(require('./routes/'));` not `app.use(require('./routes/index'));`

Comment: is this relevant to this question?